# Scipy Sparse Matrices - Inconsistent Sums

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix that I arrived at through a complicated bunch of calculations which I cannot reproduce here. I will try to find a simpler example of this.

For now, does anyone know how it might be (even remotely) possible that I could have a sparse matrix `X` with the property that:

```
In [143]: X.sum(0).sum()
Out[143]: 131138

In [144]: X.sum()
Out[144]: 327746

In [145]: X.sum(1).sum()
Out[145]: 327746

In [146]: type(X)
Out[146]: scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix
```

My only guess is that if I want to sum columns correctly, I need to first cast the matrix as csc -- which makes sense. Although one would think that the sparse package would handle column sums gracefully (or throw an error) instead of just giving a WRONG answer.

After more thought, I tried the following:

```
In [164]: X.tocsr().sum(0).sum()
Out[164]: 131138

In [165]: X.tocsc().sum(0).sum()
Out[165]: 131138

In [166]: X.tocoo().sum(0).sum()
Out[166]: 131138

In [167]: X.tolil().sum(0).sum()
Out[167]: 131138

In [168]: X.todok().sum(0).sum()
Out[168]: 131138

In [169]: X.shape
Out[169]: (196980, 43)

In [170]: X
Out[170]: 
<196980x43 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.uint16'>'
        with 70875 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [172]: X.todense().sum(0)
Out[172]: 
matrix([[170726,   1041, 117398,   3526,  13202,   3585,   2355,   1895,   1392,   2189,   2070,   2603,   1676,    496,   1194,    933,    129,
            529,    544,    256,      7,      0,      0,      0,      0,      0,      0,      0,      0,      0,      0,      0,      0,      0,
              0,      0,      0,      0,      0,      0,      0,      0,      0]], dtype=uint64)

In [173]: X.sum(0)
Out[173]: 
matrix([[39654,  1041, 51862,  3526, 13202,  3585,  2355,  1895,  1392,  2189,  2070,  2603,  1676,   496,  1194,   933,   129,   529,   544,   256,
             7,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0,     0]], dtype=uint16)
```

I should add some more context: the matrix has only non-negative entries (they are counts). In particular there were two sparse count matrices `A` and `B` which I multiplied together to get `X`.

Comment: Something seems very wrong here...

Comment: Maybe the **scipy mailing list** is more appropriate for such a question? Sounds like a bug to me. **What answer do you expect to get here**?

Comment: Ok-- will try the mailing list. Wasn't sure if perhaps there was something else I was missing. But also -- if anyone has any insight into how this might be possible (and what I mistaken assumptions I might be making) -- that would be awesome.

Comment: I think the fact that you are using uint16 and overflows might play into it. Actually thats pretty certainly all there is to it...

Comment: Actually seberg -- thank you so much! I think that's it. uint16 has a max of ~65000 and my sums here are much bigger than that. I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: @gabe yes, the thing is, numpy upcasts silently to uint32 for the sum method, the sparse matrix does not. You can calculate that `% 2**16` is exactly what you see...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so seberg answered the question. Thanks a lot. Go seberg!

He observed that the data type uint16 might be a problem. Sure enough -- uint16 maxes out around 65,000 and my sums are much bigger than that, even though my individual datapoints are much much smaller than that.

Proof in the pudding:

```
In [184]: Y = sparse.csc_matrix(X,dtype=np.uint32)

In [185]: Y.sum(0).sum()
Out[185]: 327746

In [187]: Y.sum(0)
Out[187]: 
matrix([[170726,   1041, 117398,   3526,  13202,   3585,   2355,   1895,   1392,   2189,   2070,   2603,   1676,    496,   1194,    933,    129,
            529,    544,    256,      7,      0,      0,      0,      0,      0,      0,      0,      0,      0,      0,      0,      0,      0,
              0,      0,      0,      0,      0,      0,      0,      0,      0]], dtype=uint32)
```

This explains the inconsistent sums and, changing the data type, rectifies the issue. Although, still there is the persistent problem that -- if I have a matrix with all small entries, I want to be able to use a smaller datatype for it (to save memory).

This is kind of a separate but related question:

Is there a way to gracefully handle numerical overflow problems when summing columns of sparse matrices?

Comment: Nevermind about the last question. I see now the overflow error actually was handled gracefully: scipy summed the whole matrix correctly.